# str.format() raises KeyError

Tags: python, syntax, string-formatting, delimiter, missing-data

The following code raises a `KeyError` exception:

```
addr_list_formatted = []
addr_list_idx = 0

for addr in addr_list: # addr_list is a list
    addr_list_idx = addr_list_idx + 1
    addr_list_formatted.append("""
        "{0}"
        {
        "gamedir"  "str"
        "address"  "{1}"
        }
    """.format(addr_list_idx, addr))
```

Why?

I am using Python 3.1.

Comment: You could probably accomplish the same task with a list comprehension (use `enumerate` to get the indeces).

Comment: **See also (duplicate)** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574349/python-format-string-with-custom-delimiters

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The problem is that those `{` and `}` characters you have there don't specify a key for formatting. You need to double them up, so change your code to:

```
addr_list_formatted.append("""
    "{0}"
    {{
    "gamedir"  "str"
    "address"  "{1}"
    }}
""".format(addr_list_idx, addr))
```

Comment: What if someone wanted to use JSON in Python?

Comment: @fijiaaron the double `{` in the answer is just to tell the `format` method that there is no key to format here (so they are escaped in the formated string and it shouldn't be a problem for build a JSON that way). Alternatively there is other efficient ways to manipulate strings, like the `join` method : `"".join(['{"', var_name, '":', value, '}'])`

Comment: I almost lost my mind until figured whats the problem

Comment: @DmitryKankalovich You have lost your mind, Stack Overflow, and everybody here, is just a figment of your imagination. (that's what I keep telling myself at least) :)

Answer (score 4):

Using `str.format()` to format JSON strings is not ideal because you would have to escape the curly braces, as the accepted answer notes.

While this method may be suitable for small JSON templates, it could make the template difficult to read if there are many curly braces that require escaping.

A better alternative could be [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings):

```py
from string import Template

addr_list = ["address 1, country 1", "address 2, country 2"]

addr_list_formatted = []
addr_list_idx = 0

template = Template("""
"${index}"
{
"gamedir"  "str"
"address"  "${address}"
}
""")

for addr in addr_list:
    addr_list_idx = addr_list_idx + 1
    formatted = template.substitute(index=addr_list_idx, address=addr)
    addr_list_formatted.append(formatted)
```