# Python format throws KeyError

Tags: python

The following code snippet:

```
template = "\                                                                                
function routes(app, model){\                                                                
  app.get('/preNew{className}', function(req, res){\                                         
    res.render('{className}'.ejs, {});\                                                      
  });\                                                                                       
});".format(className=className)
```

throws a KeyError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "createController.py", line 31, in <module>
    });".format(className=className) KeyError: '  app'
```

Does someone know why?

Comment: You need to double all curly braces that should not be formatted.

Comment: Have you come across [multiline strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)? If you use triple-quotes, you don't have to escape each newline.

Comment: possible duplicate of [str.format() does not work, keyError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755201/str-format-does-not-work-keyerror)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You have a number of unescaped braces in that code. Python considers all braces to be placeholders and is trying to substitute them all. However, you have only supplied one value.

I expect that you don't want all your braces to be placeholders, so you should double the ones that you don't want substituted.  Such as:

```
template = """                                                                  
function routes(app, model){{
  app.get('/preNew{className}', function(req, res){{
    res.render('{className}'.ejs, {{}});                                           
  }};                                                      
}});""".format(className=className)
```

I also took the liberty of using triple quotes for the string literal so you don't need the backslashes at the end of each line.

Comment: Really helpful answer. Thank you for sharing this with everyone. :)