# Remove scrollbar from folium map in Python

Tags: python, html, leaflet, folium

I recently started working with `folium` which is a bit web developer oriented and I'm not. So I created a map and injected a title onto it, like this:

```
m = folium.Map(location=loc,
       center=center, zoom_start=13)

title_html = '''
     <h3 align="center" style="font-size:20px"><b>Titly title</b></h3>
     ''' 
m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(title_html))
display(m)
```

[image]

But this creates a scrollbar, which makes navigating a bit uncomfortable. Before adding the title I had no problems, as you can see:

[image]

So, is there any way to add a title without adding a scrollbar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to the html's `style` properties which is mostly stated between the `<head></head>` tags. So yo can convert the variable `title_html` as below :

```
title_html = '''
     <head><style> html { overflow-y: hidden; } </style></head>
     <h3 align="center" style="font-size:20px"><b>Titly title</b></h3>
     '''
```

Comment: Nice! it worked like a charm, thanks. I guessed I could do something with the html, but my knowledge is quite basic.

Comment: Note that if you use `format()` you may have to [double the braces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9623246/812102) in order to pass the `KeyError: ' overflow-y'` error.