# Problem with string formatting when using triple quotes in Python

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

For this,

```
name='the name'
address='the address'

s = '''{
  "name": "{0}",
  "address": "{1}"
}
'''
print(s.format(name, address))
```

I expected it to print the following.

```
{
  "name": "the name",
  "address": "the address"
}
```

But I get the following error instead. Why and what is the solution?

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-eb4c74e2dd68> in <module>
      8 '''
      9 
---> 10 print(s.format(name, address))

KeyError: '\n  "name"'
```

Comment: Try removing the curly brackets.

Comment: Escape the printable brackets: `s = '''{{....`

Comment: Take look on that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2755201/8230216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer `{}` needs to be escaped for string formatting, you can do so by doubling the `{` `}`'s.

```
s = '''{{
  "name": "{0}",
  "address": "{1}"
}}
'''
```